# Is there a recyclerView equivalent in web?

Tags: java, android, spring

I have a webpage that I made with spring framework in java. In some of the pages they can get a list of clickable rows, but if you select a range that is too large fe. 1000 rows, it freezes and the javascript needs some 20 seconds to put buttons and such on each row.

I know that in android developement one would use recyclerView to load only a portion on the screen and would load more as you keep scrolling. Is there something similar I can use in my webpage to achieve a similar result?

Comment: https://github.com/darrachequesne/spring-data-jpa-datatables

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up, using was infinite scroll https://scrollmagic.io/examples/advanced/infinite_scrolling.html
then I seperated my JSP list page strictly from the "forEach" part into an another JSP document that the first JSP would call using  something like

```
    $.get("${endpointName}"+"?queryIteration="+ queryIteration+ extraVariables, function( data ) {
        $("#mycontent").append(data);
        if($("#queryCounter"+(queryIteration)).val() === 'true'){
            $("#loader").hide();
        }
```

end then in the endpoint I would add

```
    model.addAttribute("endpointName", "listMaterialTests");
    model.addAttribute("queryIteration", queryIteration);
    if(queryIteration==null || queryIteration==0)
        return "materialTestList";
    return "materialTestListRows";
```

I would modify the services to load 100 rows at a time depending on what the queryIteration value is